# What does Bureaucratic Arts II do?

Tags: glitch-2011

The description is:

> With the second level of Bureaucratic Arts, the ability to wrangle permits from the Bureaucrats becomes yours.

What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bureaucratic Arts II allows the player to obtain more types of permits from the Bureaucrats in  Bureaucratic Halls. As of now, the only item this enables you to obtain is the [General Building Permit](http://www.glitch.com/items/general-building-permit/), which is consumed in [certain phases](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsEmOAiSmSWzdG9XTzJDWXNzSkR1YXlCUVI0VTBvR1E) of Street Projects. BA II is also required in the work stages of certain projects. **tl;dr: BA II is only useful for Street Projects, and it is only rarely useful.**

It is hinted that in the future more types permits will be added. For example, in the forum post introducing Party Packs, the developers hinted that Parties will in the future require Party Permits which presumably will require BA II to obtain. There also exists the unimplemented skill Bureaucratic Arts III, which hints that the developers may expand the skill tree in this direction in the future.

Comment: Where can you find out unimplemented skills?

Comment: @fredley Look at the encyclopedia's [skill page](http://www.glitch.com/skills/). The skills that require *The Impossible Achievement* (which as per its name is impossible to obtain normally) are currently unimplemented. BA III and the Unlearning branch are currently the only ones that appears there.